# Disabling datadog-agent for good in Python application

Tags: python, datadog

Currently if you import Datadog module `datadog` in Python, it will automatically monkey-patch itself all over the place. Because of how Datadog is built, it is susceptible to causing crashes, memory leaks and compatibility issues in your application.

What is the correct way to use Datadog modules in your Python application, e.g. for type-hinting, but also ensure that Datadog doesn't do anything run-time related to your code to be sure that inference from Datadog is not causing issues in your application?

- No import time monkey-patching
- Not `sitecustomize.py` hooks getting pulled in
- etc.

For example

```py
# Make sure this import does not cause any run-time behavior change
from datadog import DogStatsd
```